# Have we ever seen a female Borg drone 'extra'?

Tags: star-trek, borg, female-characters

Certainly there have been female Borg, such as:

- [image] The Borg Queen
- [image][image] Seven of Nine
- [image][image] Riley Frazier of "Unity"
- [image][image] Marika Wilkarah of "Survival Instinct"

But have we even seen a run-of-the-mill Borg drone (i.e. not a character tied to a plot element) who was female?

Comment: My question is honestly how would you be able to tell? The only reason we know about these character is because they are costumes differently. If a woman was cast as a drone extra, except for a large breasted woman, how would you be able to tell it was a woman..(FYI, I mean that as a serious part of the discussion, not a course comment).

Comment: I like how big Seven's Borg head is, to accommodate her hair under the bald cap.

Comment: @Escoce:   Well, if you look at the page Himarm linked you'll see that you usually can tell.   Don't underestimate how clear gender usually is from facial shape.   And you are evolved to differentiate.       But I get your point that being costumed as a Borg does obscure to some degree.   For example, [this one](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/File:Borg_drone_13,_2370.jpg) who is credited as *unknown actress*, I would say I'm only 80% confident is played by a woman.

Comment: @OrangeDog:  I think you mean the Borg Queen.

Comment: @ThePopMachine No I don't. We never see her non-assimilated appearance, so her skull could be that shape anyway.

Comment: @OrangeDog:  Oh, I was assuming your comment was a response to the images above, where the back of Seven's head is not visible.

Comment: @ThePopMachine You assumed correctly. The back isn't visible, but the 
(bulging) top is.

Comment: @amarillo:  Clearly later canon, like "Unity" and "Survival Instinct" and the mere existence of Seven of Nine contradict that claim.    They are clear not de-sexed except according to that one line by Q.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Q's point is that a Borg drone doesn't have a gendered identity, regardless of its physical characteristics. It's an "it", not an individual person.

Comment: @OrangeDog:   Yes, this makes more sense, I suppose, but it still means that answer doesn't apply to the intent here.

Answer (score 13):

**Plenty, though you might not have noticed**

Here is one of the first drones the Enterprise D crew meets.

[image]

In episode Q Who, of TNG. [wiki](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Borg)

Note the early Borg design as well.

[image]

[played by Lynn Salvatori](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/File:Borg_drone_8,_2366.jpg)

[image]
[image]
[image]

All of these drones appear in [the best of both worlds](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Borg)

[This page shows that there have been lots of female drones, however, male drones do appear more dominant, as well as the costumes making it difficult to distinguish Female from Male drones.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Borg)

Comment: According to the wiki, this is the only noted female Borg drone, actress unnamed. Great answer.

Comment: found more as well, but didnt want to clog us up with too many pictures,

Comment: @Himarm:   Care to make a rough measurement of the female/male ratio?

Comment: @Himarm:   Hmm, I always thought [this one](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/File:Crippled_female_Borg.jpg) was animatronic.   I guess this Tracee Lee Cocco played her role well!

Comment: @ThePopMachine 1/3, or 1/4th of drones in TNG, and i count 1, unnamed female in voyager according to the wiki.

Comment: @Himarm I dunno. I can't tell for most of them posted here.

Comment: Lucky Locutus! ;-)

Comment: The costume of the fourth picture looks like it would have been a fun one to wear. /s