# Was Seven on her way to becoming a Borg Queen?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, seven-of-nine

I had a thought that Seven of Nine might have been set to become a Borg Queen. She's the only female Borg Drone I can think of, she is clearly more comfortable with being autonomous, has a relationship with the Borg Queen we seen in Voyager, and the Borg quickly select her that to me indicates that she was already in that line of command.

Are there any official sources that indicate this?

Comment: She's the wrong species, dude. - http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Species_125 / http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Borg_species_designations

Comment: There's loads of female borg; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124285/have-we-ever-seen-a-female-borg-drone-extra

Comment: @Valorum What does species have to do with anything. I said "a", not "the" borg queen. Is there something saying that only those from 1 given species can be Queens? That'd be silly if there was and it was 125 considering they're not #1... 

Also...oh yeah forgot about them, but the style of "armor" is different so I think that's goes more towards 7 having been selected to become a Queen at some point.

Comment: Assuming you take the cut-scenes from Star Trek Legacy as canon, and why wouldn't you :-) then being a queen is a matter of species; https://youtu.be/anMOQ3vTy9k?t=1m48s

Comment: @Valorum Because it's not canon. Also it doesn't say it's the only race that can, but that they found a particular race's women that can. It would make sense that if they find others they use others.

Comment: This is an example of a question that stems from "Small Universe Syndrome." The next Borg Queen obviously has to be a "famous" Borg with which we're already familiar. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there are countless other female Borg drones, watch "Unimatrix Zero" 
and "Survival Instinct" as 2 examples.

as for your main question the short answer is **NO** (but i may be wrong).

This is why I believe this:

- The queen says 7 was planted on voyager in the 'Dark Frontier: Part 2'. This could have been a lie but I don't think it was (when the queen did lie in that episode, 7 knew instantly. The Borg are bad lairs due to inexperience with the concept).
- The 3 cubes voyager approached with terms for negotiation, 1 happened to have a human aboard: pure coincidence, (This is when I think that the plan was conceived, to put a Human/Borg spy onto voyager, they saw an opportunity here). A human who could represent the Borg (like Locutus). They knew Janeway would not be easy to negotiate with so they beamed her to the cube with the human onboard (and only a short walk away).
- 7 was ONLY activated when Janeway refused to obey the Borgs methods -
  Borg: "human communication is inefficient, you will be assimilated",
  Janeway: "we must do nothing choose a representative or the deals
  off". If 7 was a queen  she would have been activated as a
  representative from the start.
- 7 does have a unique physiology for a Borg (the breasts mainly), but
  we don't know when she came out of the maturation chamber (yesterday,
  a year ago, who knows), the Borg seem to grow with the implants,
  which is shown in 'TNG:Q who', she might still be maturing in the
  alcove: hence all the pipe that disconnect when we first see her.
- As far as we know the queen is mainly a brain and spinal column, from
  the 2 example we have, the movie 'First Contact' & Voy:'Dark
  frontier'. Both of these queens were different people (in and out of
  universe). This strongly imply's shes a processing node for the Borg
  and just an avatar when needed. If this is true 7 would have been
  activated the moment Janeway was beamed aboard.
- Non cannon but queens are only picked from 1 species, one where the
  women have great minds (Can't remember which novel, sorry). This isn't cannon so it can be ignored if you like.
- One last thing and this is a big one, a queen listens to and gives
  instructions to the collective, whereas 7 in Voy:'Scorpion Part 2'
  gets told to take control of the earth ship, to which she replies
  "understood". This isn't how a queen behaves at all from what we've
  seen.

In short, none of this suggests a possible queen, actually the exact opposite, she just happened to be human plus shes on one of the cubes, and the Borg saw the opportunity to prey on those pesky human weaknesses (emotions). They knew they couldn't assimilate by force (the threat of losing the 8472 nano-probe data), so they used what resources they had close by, a human/borg to prey on the 'enemy weakness', (that seems very Borg to me, but she was simply a drone until they realized this).

This is my understanding. the Borg simply saw an opportunity with a human/borg close by and used it. Hope this helps and like I said it could be wrong, this is just my understanding of the events.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that she was possibly being groomed by the Borg Queen for a high ranking position. But, she was as close to a child of the queen as any one in that world could be. She was taken at a very young age, and was a favorite of the queen. She awoke some motherting instinct in the queen i believe. Seven was likely a protégé IMO.

Comment: Perhaps. Is there any sign of this in the show?

Comment: Seriously, watch the series especially from the time she arrives. And really pay attention to the episodes with flasdh backs and the ones where she and janeway go to the Borg queens world. You'll see what I mean. I'm a huge Star Trek fan, ALL of the Star Treks.

Comment: Welcome to sff.se!   This is not your typical forum.   We strive to give evidence-based answers to questions rather than debating opinion.   I suggest you [take the tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: @SusanSimmons this is a site that beats you on the head with mountains of evidance, references, proof, quotes and walls and walls of text. Anything else and you will get down voted into oblivion.